# Add a content control after an existing content control in word using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, add-in, word-contentcontrol

A little more detail:
I am inserting (lots of) content controls into a single document.
Ideas?
Current code:

```
for(let i=0;i<term.length;i++){
  Word.run(function (context) {
    let range = context.document.body
    // Queue a command to create the content control.
    let myContentControl = range.insertContentControl()
    myContentControl.tag = id[i].toString();
    myContentControl.title = id[i].toString();
    myContentControl.insertHtml(term[i], 'End');
    context.load(myContentControl, 'id');
    return context.sync().then(function () {
    console.log('Created content control with id: ' + myContentControl.id);
  });
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
    console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
  });
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to add multiple content controls in a word document ?

Comment: You need to provide more details, like what the current behavior of your code is. But as a guess, your loop should be inside the Word.run function

Comment: E.g you may have a race condition. you adding controls in a loop before the context.sync finishes. So the last controls sync is probably overriding everything since it doesnt have the changes from before because they haven't synced

Comment: I added the for loop after the word.run function but then the loop ran just once.With the above code, I am able to create multiple content controls but they're nested content controls but i want to create separate content controls. I think this because for every iteration the whole body is taken as a parameter(context.document.body). Is there a way to create disjoint content controls?

Comment: The link I referred for the above code is(search for insertContentControl) -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview

Comment: In every subsequent loop you'd need to retrieve the last content control in the document then move the target range for insertion outside of it.

Comment: I can retrieve the last control, but I don't know how to set the range outside the control,the range takes context.document.body as a parameter,so for every loop it takes the range with respect to the document body

Comment: Look at the `get​Range(range​Location)` method, using the `After` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert Paragraphs based on the number content controls you want to insert inside the word document and insert the content controls looping over the paragraphs.

```
Word.run(function (context) {
        var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
        context.load(paragraphs, 'text');
        return context.sync().then(function () {
          const loop = paragraphs.items.length;
          var contentControls;
          console.log('loop value',loop);
          for (var x = 0; x < loop; x++) {
            var paragraph;
            paragraph = paragraphs.items[x];
            contentControls = paragraph.insertContentControl();
            contentControls.tag = 'tag';
            contentControls.title = 'title';
          }
        });
      })
```